# ログにあるIPアドレスを別の文字に置き換えるためのコマンド文はどのようにしたらよいでしょうか。

Tags: linux

ログに残っているIPアドレスを別の文字に全て置き換えたいのですが、どのようにしたら良いでしょうか。
別の文字に置き換える際、別のcsvデータにある対応表を読み取って置き換えをしたいと考えております。
例として、
192.168.0.1,yamada
192.168.0.2,satou
192.168.0.3,tanaka
192.168.0.4,adachi
192.168.0.5,saitou

ログにある192.168.0.1をyamadaに、192.168.0.2をsatouに変換するといったものがLinuxで、できたらなと考えております。よろしくお願いします。